# Excel: Rewriting Data into Buckets

Tags: excel

I have the following values in an excel column:

```
11
84
167
241
520
```

I want to rewrite these column values as a group such that:

```
if cell value < 50 then A
if 50 < cell value < 100 then B
if 100 < cell value < 150 then C
if 150 < cell value < 250 then D
if cell value > 250 then E
```

I tried the following logic but it shows A for cell A1 and false for other values:

```
=IF(A1<50,"A",IF(50<A1<100,"B",IF(100<A1<150,"C",IF(150<A1<250,"D",IF(A1>250,"E")))))
```

Comment: You have a small gap in your algorithm. What if value is 250 exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not need to put the `less than "< "` expression because if it was `less than "<"` an earlier `if then` statement would have returned `true`. Note that a number such as 50, 100, 150 250 will return false as we are not using an inclusive less than expression. Less than or equals to <= may be what you need, but from your example I cant tell

```
=IF(A1<50,"A",IF(A1<100,"B",IF(A1<150,"C",IF(A1<250,"D",IF(A1>250,"E")))))
```

[image]

For future reference you have to break this up into separate statements

```
AND(50<A1,A1<100,"B")
```

vs

```
IF(50<A1<100,"B")
```